# Crandall, Pomerance - Prime Numbers: A Computational Perspective - Exercise 6.8 at page 274

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algebraic-number-theory

I am trying to solve the exercise in the title. I write it here: prove for $d,n\in \mathbb{N}$
$$\frac{3}{2}\left(\frac{d}{\ln 2}\right)^d<n\quad\Rightarrow\quad n<2\lfloor{n^{1/d}\rfloor}^d$$

I have tried to solve it in this way:
$$\frac{3}{2}\left(\frac{d}{\ln 2}\right)^d<n\quad\Rightarrow\quad
\frac{3^{1/d}}{2^{1/d}}\frac{d}{\ln 2}<n^{1/d}$$
so
$$n<2\lfloor{n^{1/d}\rfloor}^d\quad\Leftarrow\quad
n<2(n^{1/d}-1)^d\quad\Leftarrow\quad
n<2\left(\frac{3^{1/d}}{2^{1/d}}\frac{d}{\ln 2}-1\right)^d
$$
But this way is an impasse.
Then I tried in this way
$$n<2\lfloor{n^{1/d}\rfloor}^d\quad\Leftarrow\quad
n<2(n^{1/d}-1)^d\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad
2\sum_{i=0}^d{\binom{d}{i}n^{(d-i)/d}(-1)^i}-n>0
$$

But I can't proceed. Could anyone give me a hint please?

Comment: my gut feeling tells me that from the inequality one shows that $(n-1)^{1/d}\leq \lfloor n^{1/d} \rfloor$

Comment: Sorry that was nonesense the above hint wouldnt work

Comment: So here is a my hint. the function $f(x)=\frac{3^x(2^x-1)}{4^x\ln(2^x)}$ is an strictly increasing function for $x\in]0,1]$ and approaches $1$ as $x$ approaches $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb{R}}$Since you asked for a hint. I prefer to do just that. If you prove that the function $f:]0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ defined by 
$$f(x)=\frac{3^x (2^x - 1)}{4^x\ln{2^x}}$$
is strictly increasing (in $]0,1]$) and show that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}f(x) = 1$ then you can solve the problem.

**Edit:** It's been a while since my post, but I guess I also need to provide the proof of my hint and I only got the time now to do it.

Taking the derivative and multiplying by $x^2$ (because testing positivity is not affected by this) within the interval $]0,1]$ you get
$$x^2f'(x)=x\left(\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^x\ln\frac{3}{2} - \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^x\ln\frac{3}{4}\right) - \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^x (2^x-1)$$

Checking positivity of the above within $]0,1]$ is similar to checking positivity of the above divided by $(3/4)^x$. So it suffices to show that 
$$g(x):=2^x(x\ln\frac{3}{2} -1) + 1-x\ln\frac{3}{4}$$
is positive. For me, this is not immediately seen. So we take the derivative of $g$ and obtain
$$g'(x)=2^x\ln\frac{3}{2}+2^x\ln{2}(x\ln\frac{3}{2}-1)-\ln\frac{3}{4}$$

The above is clearly an increasing function for $x\in]0,1]$ and $g'(0)=0$ will be less than any $g'(a)$ for $a\in ]0,1]$ (why?). So $g$ is an increasing function. We check that $g(0)=0$ and $g(1)>1$ so $g$ takes positive values in $]0,1]$ (why?) and this implies that $f$ is increasing.

Comment: Thanks! It took me half an hour to use your hint, but at the end I succeeded. With just few manipulation the thesis turns out to be equivalent to $f(1/d)>1$.

Comment: Good job. Indeed.

Comment: By the way, I assume that you also proved that the function is increasing.

Comment: The limit is easy with l'Hopital, for the monotonicity I tried with the derivate of $\log{f(x)}$ and it results $\log{3/4} + 2^x \log{2}/(2^x-1) - 1/x$. And I'm stucked here...

Comment: I don't know if taking the derivative of $\log f(x)$ is better. But sometimes you need to take a derivative again to check for monotonicity.You want to know if there is a zero of the derivative in a given interval, sometimes the second derivative will help you with that. In particular, it could help to know if the derivative is also increasing in the interval. I'm just guessing here though.

Comment: The derivate of the derivate is still worse... It is hard to study it.